# AS3 Sprite not going behind object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a pseudo 3D collision with multiple walls. It works to an extent:
I can collide with the sides of each wall

but only on one of the walls, if I were to go to the top, It goes behind the rectangle like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnQ4M.jpg) but on the second rectangle, I go above it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBWAL.jpg) I don't why this is happening (I am a beginner in AS3). Using trace, it says that the player is at layer 0 while the wall is at layer 2, but the ball still goes above the wall.

edit: I'm using flashdevelop incase that changes anything

Edit: Changed code, it works fine, but ignores the second wall, it prints it's name but doesn't change the boolean

```
    for each (var wall in WallsList)
    {
        trace(wall.name)
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x - hitRad+.995, Character.y, true)) //col right
        {
            Character.x+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x + hitRad-.995, Character.y, true)) //col left
        {
            Character.x-=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x , Character.y- hitRad+25, true)) //col bottom
        {
            Character.y+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y+hitRad-25, true)) //col top
        {
            Character.y -= CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y+hitRad, true))  // col top #2
        {
            trace(wall.name) // prints for both walls
            Top = true; // only changes for 1 wall
        }
        if (!wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y+hitRad, true))
        {
            Top = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In col top you have `setChildIndex(Character, 0)` but everywhere else you use `setChildIndex(Character, 2)` Just make it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Bring wall object above the ball:

```
setChildIndex(wallObject, this.numChildren - 1);
```

Comment: Not working. Am I doing something wrong? Put it as      setChildIndex(r, this.numChildren - 1);

Comment: if you want wall object to be above the character all the time do the following: `for each (var r:Shape in this.WallList)
{
 if(r.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y + hitRad -1, true))
 {
  setChildIndex(r, this.numChildren - 1);
 } else {
  setChildIndex(Character, this.numChildren - 1);
 }
}` if you dont want to bring character above just remove else statement

Comment: Still not working. Now it just goes above the bottom and top when I should only go behind the rectangle at the top.

Comment: change `if(r.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y + hitRadius - 25, true))`

Comment: It works fine with 1 rectangle, but if there's more than 1, only one of them works correctly.

Comment: answer = addChid(wallObject); unless both of you explicitly like to type more than you need, I suggest to use addChild() to make an object go on top.

Comment: I've changed the code (editted the OP), it seems to ignore the second wall, it doesn't change the boolean to true but it prints the name of the wall correctly.

Comment: addChild() at this point makes no sense. Adding new objects would be overkill performance wise, when you simply can change object depth index. This whole loop can be written more simplefied. If you need character above the wall `setChildIndex(character, this.numChildren-1)` if you need wall over the character `setChildIndex(wall, this.numChildren-1)` . It works for me.